# MVVM - Open Second View Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, view, viewmodel

Edit: Example App -> http://www10.zippyshare.com/v/29730402/file.html

I'm programming an app for Windows 8 & Windows Phone. I'm using the portable class library (see this article http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2013/01/portable-mvvm-light-move-your-view.html).

My problem is: How can I open a second window by clicking on a button by using the MVVM-pattern? I don't want to do it in the behind-code.

My datacontext for the Windows 8 app looks in the xaml like this

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

which uses the ViewModel of the PCL (= ViewModel for both, W8 & WP8)

```
xmlns:vm="using:Mvvm.PCL.ViewModel"
```

I don't know how to assign 2 datacontext to my MainPage.xaml, nor do I know how to assign my MainPage.xaml to the ViewModel for my Windows 8 app.

I've tried something like this:

```
Command="{Binding DisplayView}" CommandParameter="SecondView"
```

but the program uses the ViewModel for both platforms and I can't program there the windows-assignment for the specific platforms. (it should look something like this [Opening multiple views by clicking button using MVVM silverlight approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100471/opening-multiple-views-by-clicking-button-using-mvvm-silverlight-approach) ...)

To make it clear:

I have 2 projects.
Both MainWindows of the projects refer to the ViewModel of the "MainProject".
If I want to click on a button in my MainWindow, I want to open a new view, but I can only use the ViewModel for both projects, which means that I can't use any views of the 2 projects in my ViewModel of the "MainProject".

edit: I've seen that many people use ContentControl. (Still doesn't work. Btw im new to MVVM).

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding CurrentView}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="10" />
<Button Command="{Binding DisplayView}" CommandParameter="SecondView">
```

MainViewModel.cs (For both platforms)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using Mvvm.PCL.Model;
#if NETFX_CORE 
    using Mvvm.Store.Views;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
#endif

namespace Mvvm.PCL.ViewModel
{

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>

    public MainViewModel()
    {
#if NETFX_CORE
        DisplayView = new RelayCommand<string>(DisplayViewCommandExecute);
#endif
        }

    #region Commands

    public RelayCommand<string> DisplayView { get; private set; }

    #endregion

#if NETFX_CORE

    #region CurrentView Property

    public const string CurrentViewPropertyName = "CurrentView";

    private Page _currentView;

    public Page CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentView == value)
                return;

            _currentView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CurrentViewPropertyName);
        }
    }

    private SecondView _secondview = new SecondView();
    public SecondView SecondView
    {
        get
        {
            return _secondview;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void DisplayViewCommandExecute(string viewName)
    {
        switch (viewName)
        {
            case "SecondView":
                CurrentView = _secondview;
                var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
                frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondView));
                break;
        }
    }
#endif
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of doing things in the codebehind, you should just realize when to put code there. The MVVM pattern exists to separate data/biz logic from UI/view logic, so if what you're trying to accomplish only pertains to the view, you should use the codebehind. If you try to put *everything* in your ViewModel, you're going to end up having view-specific code in your ViewModel (which breaks the MVVM pattern), and your ViewModel is going to get very messy, very fast.

Comment: My buttons are in an AppBar.

I'm using something like this now:

    <Button Click="GoToNextWindow" Command="{Binding DisplayView}" CommandParameter="SecondWindow">

    private void GoToNextWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new Mvvm.Store.ViewModel.MainViewModel();
        }

It's actually working, but only when I open the app bar, click on the button (all Bindings in my MainWindow are lost & the MainWindow is still open), close the app bar, open the app bar and click the button again.

Comment: Why do you have a Click handler and a Command handler? Usually it's one or the other, not both.

Comment: I know how I can open a new window with the command handler, but like I said before, I'm using a ViewModel for both W8 & WP8 so I can't refer to the views in the ViewModel. The MainWindow is using the ViewModel for both platforms, but if I want to change the view for the MainView of the Windows 8 app, I have to use somehow the ViewModel of the Windows 8 app (change the DataContext), instead of the ViewModel for both platforms. That's why I'm using the Click handler -> to change the DataContext, but this doesn't work very well...